# Pandas data frame replace international currency sign

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, unicode, utf-8

Working with an excel file which has international currency signs in multiple columns. In addition to that file some international language.

```
Example: Paying £40.50 doesn't make any sense for a one-hour parking. 
Example: Produkty są zbyt drogie (Polish)
Example: 15% de la population féminine n'obtient pas de bons emplois (French)
```

As a cleanup process following actions have been taken

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('\\r',' '))
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('\\n',' '))
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('\.+', ''))
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('-', ''))
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('&', ''))
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(r"[\"\',]", ''))
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('[%*]', ''), axis=1)
```

(If there is more efficient way - more than welcome)

In addition to this: Method has been created to remove stopwords

```
def cleanup(row):
    stops = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    removedStopWords = " ".join([str(i) for i in row.lower().split() 
    return removedStopWords
```

to apply this method to all columns in the data frame that contains above examples:

```
df = df.applymap(self._row_cleaner)['ComplainColumns']
```

but `UnicodeEncodeError` has been the biggest problem. One of the first place it throws this error on British Pound Sign.

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa3' in position 646: ordinal not in range(128)`

Tried following: 
`df = df.apply(lambda x: x.unicode.replace(u'\xa3', ''))` gut didn't work.

Goal is to replace all none alphabetical characters to `''` or `' '`

Comment: Would this help `df = df.replace('[^\w\s]','',regex=True)`?

Comment: Nope it replaced everything to w

Comment: I think its working slight issue... `AttributeError: ("'float' object has no attribute 'lower'", u'occurred at index Positive')` inside cleanup method `removedStopWords = " ".join([str(i) for i in row.lower().split() if i not in stops])`

Comment: maybe you need to use `df.astype(str)` and then `apply` there might be `Nans` in the dataframe

Comment: thats it.. wanna write as an answer so i can accept?

Comment: I know just to make sure you get more credit than having it as comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to replace all the characters other than [A-z0-9] then you can use replace with regex i.e

```
 df = df.replace('[^\w\s]','',regex=True)
```

There might be missing data in the dataframe so you might need to use astype(str), since you are using list comprehension with `.lower()`, Nan will be considered as float.

```
df.astype(str).apply(cleanup)
```